# How do I find guitar chords to play while I sing "Frozen Heart" from Disney's Frozen?

Tags: theory, guitar, sheet-music

**How can I figure out which chords to play while I sing "Frozen Heart" from Disney's *Frozen*?**

---

I'm a beginning guitar player, and I like playing Disney songs. I've learned most of the songs from the movie *Frozen*, but I'm struggling with "Frozen Heart".

Here's the song:

I searched the internet and couldn't find anyone who had written down guitar chords for it, so I set out to do it myself. If I play `Am` up to "this icy" and then `Dm`, `Am`, `E`, `Am`, it sounds ok. Not quite right but not bad. After that I'm lost, though. I decided to turn to the sheet music, which I bought, in order to help me.

Here's the first page (it's free) of the [sheet music](http://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/frozen-heart-digital-sheet-music/19948393?gclid=CjwKEAjw-JqgBRCAyqjoic27nlQSJABBTpFEsSi1_DpUwXEmlkda9CDdwGITUmpAgSYm5aRqNlwnBhoCLfPw_wcB&d=sem_SFD&popup=false&mkwid=g4Joy64R&ac=1&pdv=c&pcrid=51883202062).

I saw [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9861/transcribing-piano-chords-for-guitar) SE post, and I think what I'm trying to do is vary similar to what he was asking about.

However, I'm having a lot of trouble with it. I have no experience reading music, but looking at the sheet music I think the first few notes are: `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `A`, `B`, `A`, `G`. What chord should I play with that?

I notice that above "born" is `D5`, and playing a `D5` sounds pretty good. I think the chord should change at "icy", but playing `D5` all the way up to "cut!" (which has an `A5`) doesn't sound horrible. But, looking at the rest of the sheet music, the listed chords barely change (Mostly `D5` -> `A5` -> `D5`) and really don't sound good at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, a vocal arrangement or piano arrangement might be your best bet. Guitar is a C instrument so you should be able to follow any of the chord progressions outlined in a piano arrangement. You might have to actually buy the sheet music, though.

**Vocal Arrangement:** Usually for a vocal arrangement the chords are specified as to facilitate  a musical accompaniment that's independent from instrumentation. These chords could be valuable to you. If they sound funny, or don't fit your vocal range, you can shift them to a different key, which is probably the subject of a different question.

**Piano Arrangement:** Ideally the chord progression will be outlined throughout the piece. If it isn't, you may be able to follow the notes on the piano to determine what chord is being played and what sounds best. This approach has the added benefit of having a lot of different chord voicing to choose from, and a lot of melodic lines to spice up your guitar arrangement.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi ReimTime! I bought the sheet music that I linked in my question. I was under the impression it IS a piano arrangement. What did I buy exactly?

Comment: It looks like you bought a piano/vocal arrangement. The piano part is the lower half (the two bottom staves) and the vocal part is the topmost line. Unfortunately, no chords seems to be listed, which means you might have your work cut out for you. I would try working through the treble clef chords on the the piano part, as it looks like the left hand is composed of mostly single whole notes (I'm just working off the first page, here). The left hand (bass clef) of the piano part might be a strong representation of the chord roots throughout the song. Then you just find a voicing you like.

Answer (score 2):

I found plenty chord progressions on Google.
One of them is this one: 
http://chordify.net/chords/disney-frozen-frozen-heart-mg137b

I can't check if they are correct since I do not have any guitar at my work place :).

Answer (score 0):

Several books of sheet music for the soundtrack include chord symbols and, in one case, guitar tabs. All include "Frozen Heart".

- *Frozen (E-Z Play Today Volume 212)*: Focuses on basic triads, though seventh chords are occasionally given as alternatives. Songs: 1. Let It Go; 2. Do You Want To Build A Snowman?; 3. Fixer Upper; 4. For The First Time In Forever; 5. Frozen Heart; 6. In Summer; 7. Love Is An Open Door; 8. Reindeer(s) Are Better Than People.
- *Frozen (Big Note)*: Easy piano version with notes in large print; chord symbols (not in large print) include seventh chords and sus chords. Songs: As above, but also includes "For the First Time in Forever (Reprise)".
- *Frozen (Easy Piano)*: A step beyond the Big Note version in piano difficulty; chord symbols include seventh chords, sus chords, and slash chords. Same song list as Big Note plus "Heimr Arnadalr" and "Vuelie".
- *Frozen (Piano/Vocal/Guitar)*: The "official" version. Includes tabs and more specific, accurate, and frequent chord changes. Same songs as Easy Piano.

All books are published by Hal Leonard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think those 'A5' and 'D5' reflect the whole harmony. Those are very simplified chords (also known as 'power chords'). They have their time and place but I don't think it's what this melody uses.

Personally, I find that piano arrangements are not great for guitar. All you want are the (proper) chord symbols.

You could try one of the many chord sites. There is one suggestion here:

https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/misc-cartoons/frozen-frozen-heart-chords-2355925

The tune sounds quite minor-ish to me, so their Dm version sounds about right. They change to A (the V) for a nice resolution back in 'frozen heart'. Worth giving it a go?